# Switched to Yarn, TypeScript failing on some deps for some people

Tags: typescript, npm, yarnpkg

We have a large maven project with a few UI sub-projects that we switched from `npm` to `yarn` to get build times down. For most of the team (or the CI environment) this didn't cause any problems, but for two people, the TypeScript compiler could no longer resolve something. It was different in each case, but it was always something common, such as 'moment', and in each case the packages were there on the file system.

This caused failures in both Jest tests and webpack builds. I'm guessing it has more to do with the TypeScript compiler than Yarn.

I've tried to look it up, but haven't found anything, Does the TypeScript compiler cache dependencies somewhere? Is there a way to clear it?

One person gave up and got a fresh clone (no problems), but that seems a bit drastic, and I'm really curious about the root cause / scalpel solution to this.

Anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: There is `--traceResolution` command line parameter for TypeScript compiler, it will generate tons of information about which modules it had tried to find and where it had found or not found them. You could try and see if there is anything obvioulsly wrong or different from the same log in another configuration.

Comment: Great idea. The last person having problems just nuked his work-space, unfortunately. Won't be able to try this unless it resurfaces, which I can't hope for. :)